# How to calculate AvgD, RMSD, VOE, and VD evaluation metrics for segmentation results?

Tags: python, matlab, image-segmentation, evaluation

I am doing medical image segmentation and working on 3D images, and have two images one is ground truth (gt), and one the segmentation prediction results (segm), I need to calculate two other metrics

- average absolute surface distance (AvgD) in mm,
- the average root mean square surface distance (RMSD) in mm,
- the volumetric overlap error (VOE) in percent,
- the relative volume difference (VD) in percent.

[image]
[image]

Where R is `gt` and S is `segm`. In python, the intersection can be calculated
`np.logical_and(segm, gt)`.
But I have no idea how these four evaluation metrics can be calculated. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: The intersection in matlab can be computed as 'logical_and=segm & gt' in Matlab. But I think you are more interested in Python than in Matlab, eventhough you put matlab as a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `segm` and `gt` are binary ndarrays, you can compute VOE and VD:

```
voe = 100 * (1. - np.logical_and(segm, gt).sum() / float(np.logical_or(segm, gt)))
vd = 100 * (segm.sum() - gt.sum()) / float(gt.sum())
```

Note that you can use `.sum()` of a binary mask in order to compute its "size", that is  |S| = `segm.sum()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, once i am trying to run it it shows this error: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` . `segm` and `gt` are two binary images 256x256 size. what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some surface distance based metrics.

- Hausdorff distance
- Hausdorff distance 95% percentile
- Mean (Average) surface distance
- Median surface distance
- Standard deviation of surface distance

https://pypi.org/project/seg-metrics/

This is a simple package to compute different metrics for Medical image segmentation(images with suffix .mhd, .mha, .nii, .nii.gz or .nrrd), and write them to csv file.

An example:

Install this package at first. `pip install seg-metrics`

```
import seg_metrics.seg_metrics as sg

labels = [0, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 , 8]
gdth_file = 'data/gdth.mhd'  # ground truth image full path
pred_file = 'data/pred.mhd'  # prediction image full path
csv_file = 'metrics.csv'

metrics = sg.write_metrics(labels=labels[1:],  # exclude background
                  gdth_path=gdth_file,
                  pred_path=pred_file,
                  csv_file=csv_file, 
                  metrics=['hd', 'msd'])
```